# Package naming: error exporting variable

Tags: go

I have a directory structure like this:

```
Animal/
  dog/
    chiwawa.go
  rabbit.go
```

Both `chiwawa.go` and `rabbit.go` are packaged named: "package animal" at the top of the file. However when I try to use a variable `var Food = apple` from `chiwawa.go` in `rabbit.go`, I get error - `undefined: Food`.

I don't have any problems when I place `chiwawa.go` directly under `Animal` without the `dog` directory.

Is this intentional in Go? Can I work around this while retaining the package names and directory structure?

Answer (score 0):

It is intentional. Packages in Go are imported using a directory path. So, "animal" and "animal/dog" are two different packages *even if you give them the same package name*.

To demonstrate this, I wrote the following example set of files:

```
~/go/src/test/
├── animal
│   ├── animal.go
│   └── dog
│       └── dog.go
└── test.go
```

animal/animal.go

```
package animal

type Species string
```

animal/dog/dog.go

```
package animal

// In package "animal" importing a package "animal"
import "test/animal"

type Dog struct {
    Species animal.Species
    Breed   string
}
```

test.go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "test/animal/dog"
)

func main() {
    d := animal.Dog{}
    fmt.Printf("%#v", d)
}
```

Notice that dog.go imports the "test/animal" package and references it as "animal".

Furthermore notice that test.go imports "test/animal/dog" to get access to the "Dog" struct type. If it imports, "test/animal", the error (undefined: animal.Dog) is generated.